# In-line MathJax equations not rendering on Shiny app hosted at shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, mathjax, shiny-server, shinyapps, shinymanager

I have a shiny app that includes MathJax equations and some script to allow for in-line equations. It works fine the RStudio IDE but not when hosted on shinyapps.io.

I have narrowed down interference to a `shinymanager::secure_app()` function. It may have something to do with the `head_auth` argument within `secure_app()`, but I cannot figure it out.

For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

# credentials <- data.frame(
#   user = c(""),
#   password = c(""),
#   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
# )


ui <- 
  # secure_app( 
    fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        mainPanel(
          tags$div(HTML(
            "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config' >
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}
                              });
            </script >
            ")),
          p(withMathJax("$$n_{\\sf larvae_0} \\sim {\\sf binomial}(n_{\\sf egg}, \\pi_{\\sf egg})$$"), style="text-align: center; font-size:20px;"),
          
          
          p(withMathJax("where $n_{\\sf larvae_0}$ is the number of age-0 larvae, 
                          $\\pi_{\\sf egg}$ is the Beverton-Holt estimated egg to larva survival probability... ")),
        )
    )
)
# )


server <- function(input, output) {
  secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

returns text that includes in-line equations in both RStudio and when hosted (published) to shinyapps.io:

[image]

When I activate the `secure_app()` part, the in-line text still renders properly up in RStudio IDE viewer, but DOES NOT render as an equation in the hosted app on shinyapps.io:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c(""),
  password = c(""),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


ui <- 
  secure_app(
    fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        mainPanel(
          tags$div(HTML(
            "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config' >
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}
                              });
            </script >
            ")),
          p(withMathJax("$$n_{\\sf larvae_0} \\sim {\\sf binomial}(n_{\\sf egg}, \\pi_{\\sf egg})$$"), style="text-align: center; font-size:20px;"),
          
          
          p(withMathJax("where $n_{\\sf larvae_0}$ is the number of age-0 larvae, 
                          $\\pi_{\\sf egg}$ is the Beverton-Holt estimated egg to larva survival probability... ")),
        )
    )
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the in-line math delimiters to something other than `$` resolves the issue, although it is not clear what the conflict is with using `$`. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998981/9096420), we can add `\\( \\)` as a delimiter:

```
  tags$div(HTML("<script type='text/x-mathjax-config' >
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\\\(','\\\\)']]}
        });
        </script >
        ")),
```

Now

```
p(withMathJax("where \\(n_{\\sf larvae_0}\\) is the number of age-0 larvae, 
              \\(\\pi_{\\sf egg}\\) is the Beverton-Holt estimated egg to larva survival probability... ")),

p(withMathJax("where $n_{\\sf larvae_0}$ is the number of age-0 larvae, 
              $\\pi_{\\sf egg}$ is the Beverton-Holt estimated egg to larva survival probability... ")),
```

Results in them both working in the RStudio IDE:
[image]

But only the `\\( \\)` delimiter works once the app is published (hosted) on shinyapps.io:
[image]